# Mostrar reporte Jasper en Navegador WILDFLY 9

Tags: jasper-reports, wildfly

Tengo una aplicación web que genera una archivo .pdf en disco y tambien quiero llamarlo para mostrar en el browser directamente. Corre en Wildfly 9 y el proceso de generar el archivo en disco no tiene problemas, pero al querer mostrarlo en el navegador no muestra y tampoco me arroja un error, les copio el código para generar los archivo, llevo una semana probando de todo y no hay caso, y anteriormente hacia lo mismo en JBOSS AS7 y funcionaba sin drama.

```
public void testBuildPdf1() {
        final String REPORT_PATH= "C:\\tools\\prueba.pdf";
        FacesContext facesContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        String report=facesContext.getExternalContext().getRealPath("reportes//rptExtracto.jasper");
        String logoCabeza=facesContext.getExternalContext().getRealPath("imagenes//logoCabeza.jpg");
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource datosRubro= this.getFuncionario();


        try {           
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("LogoCGR", logoCabeza);          
            HttpServletResponse response= (HttpServletResponse)facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
//          JasperReport reportCompile= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, datosRubro);
            //genera el pdf en disco
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, REPORT_PATH);
           //send to the browser

            byte[] reportToPdf= JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setContentLength(reportToPdf.length);
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+ report + ".pdf");
                ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                out.write(reportToPdf);
                facesContext.responseComplete();
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR AL EXPORTAR!!");
            }

    }

    public JRBeanCollectionDataSource getFuncionario(){
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parametros.put("codigoFuncionario",this.idFuncionario);
        parametros.put("anio", 2018);
        parametros.put("mes", 7);
        List<AdmFuncionarioDTO> listaFun=funcionarioService.listar(0,-1, "f.id", "ASC", parametros).getLista();

        for (AdmFuncionarioDTO f: listaFun){    
            System.out.println("NOMBRE: "+f.getNombre());
            for(GenMovimientoSalarialDTO m : f.getListaMovimientos()) {
                System.out.println("MONTO: "+ m.getMovimientoImporte());
                System.out.println("MONTO: "+ m.getMovimientoDescripcion());
            }
        }
```

estas son las dependencias en mi POM:

            javax.servlet
            servlet-api
            2.5
            provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>py.gov.cgr</groupId>
        <artifactId>rrhh-extracto</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING FRAMEWORK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY FRAMEWORK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- REPORTES -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxp-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-digester3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-pdfa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: ¿Has comprobado el log?

Comment: si y no arroja absolutamente nada.....no en la consola....de hecho el proceso de creacion del PDF en disco realiza sin problemas...solo mostrar en el browser no realiza

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer tu método de la siguiente manera:

```
public void testBuildPdf1() {
    final String REPORT_PATH = "C:\\tools\\prueba.pdf";
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String report = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRealPath("reportes//rptExtracto.jasper");
    String logoCabeza = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRealPath("imagenes//logoCabeza.jpg");
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource datosRubro = this.getFuncionario();

    try {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("LogoCGR", logoCabeza);
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, datosRubro);            

        // Mostrando el documento
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = null;
        httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + report + ".pdf");
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf; name='" + report + ".pdf'");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR AL EXPORTAR!!");
    }

}
```

Creo que lo te hace falta es lo del `response` del `servlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo genero el PDF con jasper, y lo guardo en fase de desarrollo en un folder dentro del proyecto.
Una vez generado y  guardado el pdf, con un nombre especifico, y tambien en el directorio del proyecto en fase de desarrollo, lo muestro por el navegador de la siguiente forma;

Aqui te adjunto un ejemplo

```
    @GetMapping("/report")
public String generateReport(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) {

     employeeReportService.generateReport(request, response);

     try {
         byte[] documentInBytes = mostrar("reporte.pdf");       
         //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"report.pdf\"");
         response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
         response.setContentType("application/pdf");
         response.setContentLength(documentInBytes.length);
         response.getOutputStream().write(documentInBytes);
     } catch (Exception ioe) {
     } finally {
     }
     return null;
}


private byte[] mostrar(String filename) {

    byte[] b = null;

    Path pathFoto = getPath(filename);

    try {
        b = Files.readAllBytes(pathFoto);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b;
}

public Path getPath(String filename) {

    return Paths.get("src/main/resources/jasper").resolve(filename).toAbsolutePath();

}
```